# Skype status field for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: custom-field-types

Is this Skype status field available for SharePoint 2010 also? I did a quick Google search and couldn't find.

http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/

Comment: Field types for 2007 generally work in 2010 with the possibility of some cosmetic issues. Have you tried it? Are you able to give us an answer?

Answer (score 1):

According to this user (http://skypestatusfield.codeplex.com/discussions/252897) it does not work as expected with 2010.  The source code is in the project, so you could download it and troubleshoot through making it 2010 compatible if you were so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I did a blog post about adding the skype status information to the User Profiles in 2007.  You may be able to use some of the information in that to either recreate it, or troubleshoot the other project.

http://www.mikeoryszak.com/sharepoint/using-jquery-to-customize-the-user-profile-display